# Symfony Webpack Encore duplicated CSS

Tags: css, symfony, webpack, sass, webpack-encore

I followed [this](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/encore/split-chunks.html) (splitEntryChunks) tutorial in order to understand how the files are splitted when using Webpack Encore and Symfony.

Unfortunately I still don't understand it very well and I keep getting many duplications. I have the following **app.scss** file:

```
// Config
@import "vars/_vars.scss";
@import "mixins/_fontface.scss";
@import "base/_common.scss";
```

This file contains the **basic style** for the site and **is always imported in base.html.twig**:

```
    <head>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
```

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // [...]
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('homepage', './assets/js/homepage.js')

    .splitEntryChunks()
    // [...]
;
```

Now I have a homepage.scss file which contains specific code for the homepage and inherits from base.html.twig. This is the homepage.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_link_tags('homepage') }}
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the **homepage.scss** (notice the app.scss import):

```
@import "../app.scss";
@import "../components/_intro.scss";
```

Now it's all working correctly but I have the following generated CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/homepage.css">
```

The second file (**homepage.css**) also **contains the entire app.css file** (which is also imported the line before).

How can I avoid this?

Note: if I don't use the `@import "../app.scss";` in homepage.scss I get an "Unused variable" error during compilation.

Comment: Only import the files you need. For example `@import "vars/_vars.scss";` in `homepage.scss`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem since the `_vars.scss` would still be duplicated.

Comment: But arent these just sass vars? I just assumed that this is the case... Sry.

Comment: Sorry, yes they are just sass variables, Maybe it's ok if they are duplicated?

Comment: Sass variables do not appear in your output. Re-using them is one of the core advantages of sass I would say.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is, that you cannot prevent duplicates in sass/css assets by creating split chunks (or in Webpack 4 cache groups).

When doing

```
@import "../app.scss";
@import "../components/_intro.scss";
```

`homepage.scss` will always include the `app.scss`. That is a feature - not a bug.

You could

1. Use [the postcss loader](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader) with [css nano](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano) and enable: [discardduplicates](https://cssnano.co/optimisations/discardduplicates). This would probably mean, that all css must be in one large file (do not know exactly)
2. Rearrange the sass files content in a more modular way. That globally used mixins and variables are in one file.
3. Try importing `import '../components/_intro.scss';` in your javascript files and not in the sass files. Maybe this will make a difference.

Comment: I tried importing them in JS instead of in the SASS but unfortunately it doesn't make any difference :(